Use debian12 image instead of rockylinux8 in postgresql ansible role
I'm using postgresql ansible role from jeff geerling repo (https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-postgresql). By default, the molecule.yml use rockylinux8 image. I tried to use debian12 instead but i get this error when executing "molecule converge" :
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [instance]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to create temporary 
directory. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions 
on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path 
rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. Failed command was: ( umask 77 && 
mkdir -p \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp- 
1718206123.0893037-17764-260107051640399 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1718206123.0893037-17764- 
260107051640399=\"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718206123.0893037-17764-260107051640399 
`\" ), exited with result 255", "unreachable": true}

I don't get this error with rockylinux8 image.
Content of molecule.yml :
---
role_name_check: 1
dependency:
  name: galaxy
  options:
    ignore-errors: true
driver:
  name: podman
platforms:
  - name: instance
    image: "geerlingguy/docker-${MOLECULE_DISTRO:-debian12}-ansible:latest"
    command: ${MOLECULE_DOCKER_COMMAND:-""}
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw
    cgroupns_mode: host
    privileged: true
    pre_build_image: true
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  playbooks:
    converge: ${MOLECULE_PLAYBOOK:-converge.yml}

Content of converge.yml :
---
- name: Converge
  hosts: all
  become: true

  vars:
    postgresql_databases:
      - name: example
    postgresql_users:
      - name: jdoe

  pre_tasks:
    # The Fedora 30+ container images have only C.UTF-8 installed
    - name: Set database locale if using Fedora 30+ or RedHat 8+
      set_fact:
        postgresql_databases:
          - name: example
            lc_collate: 'C.UTF-8'
            lc_ctype: 'C.UTF-8'
      when:
        - ( ansible_distribution == 'Fedora' and ansible_distribution_major_version >= '30') or
          ( ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' and ansible_distribution_major_version in ['8','9'])

    - name: Update apt cache.
      apt: update_cache=true cache_valid_time=600
      changed_when: false
      when: ansible_os_family == 'Debian'

  roles:
    - role: geerlingguy.postgresql

  post_tasks:
    - name: Verify postgres is running.
      command: "{{ postgresql_bin_path }}/pg_ctl -D {{ postgresql_data_dir }} status"
      changed_when: false
      become: true
      become_user: postgres

I tried to set "ansible_remote_tmp: /tmp" in converge.yml but still get ther error : "exited with result 255, stderr output: Error: can only create exec sessions on running containers: container state improper"
"podman ps" result :
CONTAINER ID                                                      IMAGE                                                 COMMAND               CREATED        STATUS                      PORTS       NAMES
e7e659c8043c5e9d092efe71a67d2b9ba57192f5060e97177b77a706bf7e6c7d  docker.io/geerlingguy/docker-debian12-ansible:latest  /lib/systemd/systemd  3 minutes ago  Exited (255) 3 minutes ago              instance

